# Create rotated textboxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made code in VBA Word to do exactly the thing I want to do. I would like to ask if there are ways so that Word implements this faster?

```
Sub ReadyForPrinting()

    Dim oShp As Word.Shape
    Dim i As Long

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
        If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            oShp.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx")

    Dim client As Shape
    Set client = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=95, Top:=115, Width:=500, Height:=20)
    client.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(6, 4)
    client.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    client.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    client.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
    With client.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim requestdate_word As Shape
    Set requestdate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=420, Top:=127, Width:=500, Height:=20)
    requestdate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(6, 15)
    requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    requestdate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With requestdate_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim clientlocation As Shape
    Set clientlocation = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=95, Top:=124, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    clientlocation.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(7, 4)
    clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    clientlocation.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With clientlocation.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With


    Dim contactperson_word As Shape
    Set contactperson_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=110, Top:=138, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    contactperson_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(8, 4)
    contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    contactperson_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With contactperson_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim telno_word As Shape
    Set telno_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=400, Top:=150, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    telno_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(8, 15)
    telno_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    telno_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    telno_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With telno_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim workdescription As Shape
    Dim workd As String, r As Integer
    Set workdescription = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=200, Top:=198, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    r = 14
    Do
        workd = workd & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 1) & vbNewLine
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until r = 15

    workdescription.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = workd
    workdescription.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    workdescription.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    workdescription.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2.8
    With workdescription.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim inspectedby_word As Shape
    Set inspectedby_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=80, Top:=243, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    inspectedby_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(18, 1)
    inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    inspectedby_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
    With inspectedby_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim datestarted As Shape
    Set datestarted = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=135, Top:=258, Width:=300, Height:=20)
    datestarted.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(20, 5)
    datestarted.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    datestarted.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    datestarted.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With datestarted.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim datefinished As Shape
    Set datefinished = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=442, Top:=270, Width:=300, Height:=20)
    datefinished.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(20, 15)
    datefinished.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    datefinished.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    datefinished.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With datefinished.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim inspecteddate_word As Shape
    Set inspecteddate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=236, Top:=250, Width:=500, Height:=20)
    inspecteddate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(18, 8)
    inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    inspecteddate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 3
    With inspecteddate_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim confirmedby_word As Shape
    Set confirmedby_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=373, Top:=252, Width:=500, Height:=20)

    confirmedby_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(18, 11)
    confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    confirmedby_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With confirmedby_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim confirmeddate_word As Shape
    Set confirmeddate_word = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=510, Top:=255, Width:=500, Height:=20)
    confirmeddate_word.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(18, 17)
    confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    confirmeddate_word.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With confirmeddate_word.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    'merge nalang ang items. :)

    Dim materials As Shape
    Set materials = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=44, Top:=300, Width:=500, Height:=300)

    Dim mats As String
    Dim mats2 As String
    mats = ""
    r = 23

    Do
        mats = mats & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 1) & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 3) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 5) & vbNewLine
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until r = 42

    materials.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = mats

    materials.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    materials.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    materials.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2.4
    With materials.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With



    Dim materials2 As Shape
    Set materials2 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=440, Top:=314, Width:=400, Height:=400)

    r = 23

    Do
        mats2 = mats2 & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 15) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 17) & vbNewLine
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until r = 42


    materials2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = mats2


    materials2.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    materials2.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    materials2.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2.5
    With materials2.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim mattotal As Shape
    Set mattotal = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=520, Top:=515, Width:=300, Height:=20)

    mattotal.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(43, 17)
    mattotal.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    mattotal.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    mattotal.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

    With mattotal.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With



    'merge labor number of days rate
    Dim labor As Shape
    Dim lab As String
    Set labor = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=44, Top:=545, Width:=800, Height:=500)

    r = 46

    Do
        lab = lab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 1) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 5) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 15) & vbTab & vbTab & exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(r, 17) & vbNewLine
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until r = 51

    labor.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = lab
    labor.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    labor.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    labor.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1.5
    With labor.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With



    Dim labtotal As Shape
    Set labtotal = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=525, Top:=625, Width:=300, Height:=20)

    labtotal.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(52, 17)
    labtotal.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    labtotal.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    labtotal.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

    With labtotal.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim totalcost As Shape
    Set totalcost = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=525, Top:=640, Width:=300, Height:=20)

    totalcost.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(53, 17)
    totalcost.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    totalcost.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    totalcost.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2

    With totalcost.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With



    Dim preparedby As Shape
    Set preparedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=225, Top:=680, Width:=300, Height:=20)
    preparedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(57, 7)
    preparedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    preparedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    preparedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 2
    With preparedby.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim checkedby As Shape
    Set checkedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=355, Top:=680, Width:=300, Height:=20)
    checkedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(57, 12)
    checkedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    checkedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    checkedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1
    With checkedby.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Dim approvedby As Shape
    Set approvedby = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=480, Top:=683, Width:=300, Height:=20)
    approvedby.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = exWb.Sheets("2").Cells(57, 16)
    approvedby.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    approvedby.ThreeD.RotationY = 0
    approvedby.ThreeD.RotationZ = 1

    With approvedby.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    Documents.Save NoPrompt:=True, _
    OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat

    objExcel.Quit

    Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Soo ... ummmm ... what does the code do? I can't read your mind, and I'm pretty sure most of the other users can't either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically just a series of sequential instructions, featuring many repeated blocks.

Don't worry about performance. Worry about making your code easier to change - by *future you*, or by whoever inherits it.

[As Vogel612 noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174157/create-rotated-textboxes#comment330537_174157), without the post title "Create rotated textboxes" the only way to find out what this code does, is to read through all of it. *And it's a long procedure that does many things*.

*Too many things*.

The name `ReadyForPrinting` (kudos for proper `PascalCase`!) doesn't say much. If all I'm seeing is the call site, I could infer that the procedure deals with page setup or something.

So *what does it do* exactly?

> ```
> Dim oShp As Word.Shape
> Dim i As Long
>
> For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
>     Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
>     If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then
>         oShp.Delete
>     End If
> Next i
> ```

This first loop does one thing already: it removes all `msoTextBox` shapes in the `ActiveDocument`. That's *one concern* on its own - you could conceivably have a procedure whose entire purpose is to do just that. *Extract* it to its own scope.

*Then* think of performance. You're iterating an *object collection*. [Object collections are iterated up to 27 times faster with a `For Each` loop, vs. a `For` loop, which is much more efficient when iterating *arrays*](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/).

```
Private Sub RemoveTextBoxShapes(ByVal doc As Word.Document)
    Dim currentShape As Word.Shape
    For Each currentShape In doc.Shapes
        If currentShape.Type = msoTextBox Then currentShape.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

By passing in a `Word.Document` parameter, you remove all external dependencies in this scope - the procedure could be given the `ActiveDocument`, or any other `Word.Document` instance; which *specific* document it's working with is irrelevant. The procedure takes a document, iterates its shapes, deletes textboxes.

[Avoid *Systems Hungarian* notation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/), it serves absolutely no purpose, doesn't make the code any clearer, and hurts readability. Avoid *disemvoweling* too. Between `oShp` and `currentShape`, I'm not hesitating a split-second about which one I want to see in code I'm maintaining.

---

Next the script opens up an Excel workbook.

> ```
> Dim objExcel As Object
> Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx")
> ```

Again, mind Systems Hungarian; that `obj` prefix is of no use. I would have named the instance `xlApp` or something similar - `objExcel` hints at the *type library*, not at `Excel.Application`. And why is it late-bound? Late-bound calls against `Object` are resolved at run-time, which means run-time overhead, which means [ever so slightly] slower execution. But the single most important/annoying thing late-bound calls do, is that they move all compile-time checks over to run-time - this means you lose *IntelliSense* and *auto-complete* while typing it out, and the compiler won't bother resolving these calls, so if you make a typo you'll get a run-time error (438 / *object doesn't support this property or method*) instead of a compile-time error, even if `Option Explicit` is specified.

So I would add an actual reference to the Excel type library, and declare `objExcel`/`xlApp` like so:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

It's important to make that two steps, otherwise declaring it `As New` would cause issues down the line, as *auto-instantiated* local object variables are rather [hard to destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116714/1188513).

Every single subsequent use of `objExcel` (and `exWb`) serves to dereference the `Sheets("2")` object reference... 27 times to be exact. That `Sheets("2")` worksheet *wants* to be its own variable, desperately.

Get this into its own `Function`:

```
Private Function GetSourceSheet(ByVal xlApp As Excel.Application, ByVal path As String, Optional ByRef outBook As Excel.Workbook) As Excel.Worksheet
    Set outBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set GetSourceSheet = outBook.Worksheets("2")
End Function
```

Notice the `ReadOnly:=True` parameter: if you're going to open a file only to *read* from it, there's no need to *write-lock* it for other users.

And then invoke it *once*:

```
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlSheet = GetSourceSheet(xlApp, SOURCE_WORKBOOK_PATH, xlBook)
```

Now declare a module-level constant, and you've just eliminated a *magic literal*:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const SOURCE_WORKBOOK_PATH As String = "C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx"
```

The 27 instances of `exWb.Sheets("2")` can now all be replaced with references to the returned `xlSheet`, and you can use the `xlBook` reference to explicitly close it before you shut down the Excel instance:

```
xlBook.Close 'SaveChanges:=False
xlApp.Quit
```

---

The rest of the code is essentially the same actions, carried out as many times as needed... and spelled out entirely, every time. A bit of *abstraction* wouldn't hurt:

- Add, position and rotate a new `Shape`, keep a reference to the object, and hide the line.

You're declaring and holding on to 21 `Shape` object instances, and actually *need* a grand total of... none. Extract a procedure here:

```
Private Sub CreateTextBox(ByVal parent As Shapes, ByVal info As TextBoxInfo)
    With parent.AddTextBox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Top:=info.Top, Left:=info.Left, Width:=info.Width, Height:=info.Height)
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = info.Text
        With .ThreeD
            .RotationX = info.RotationX
            .RotationY = info.RotationY
            .RotationZ = info.RotationZ
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

All that's left to do now, is come up with some `TextBoxInfo` to hold the text, position, size and rotation of every textbox we need to add - and then we could just iterate a collection of `TextBoxInfo` instances and replace all that repetitive code with a simple loop:

```
Dim info As TextBoxInfo
For Each info In textBoxInfos
    CreateTextBox ActiveDocument.Shapes, info
Next
```

So what's `TextBoxInfo` anyway? I'd go with a simple class module - heck, it could be as simple as this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Text As String
Public Top As Long
Public Left As Long
Public Width As Long
Public Height As Long
Public RotationX As Long
Public RotationY As Long
Public RotationZ As Long
```

These *public fields* compile down to `Property Get` and `Property Let` accessors - ideally you would define these property accessors explicitly, but this post is getting long enough as it is.

You could even give it a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute and a *factory method* - in which case I'd definitely go with a private type and explicit property members:

```
'Rubberduck annotation controls the invisible VB_PredeclaredId attribute value:
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit
Private Type TInfo
    Text As String
    Top As Long
    Left As Long
    Width As Long
    Height As Long
    RotationX As Long
    RotationY As Long
    RotationZ As Long
End Type
Private this As TInfo

Public Property Get Text() As String
    Text = this.Text
End Property

Public Property Let Text(ByVal value As String)
    this.Text = value
End Property

'(other properties..)

Public Property Get Self() As TextBoxInfo
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Function Create(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Top As Long, ByVal Left As Long, ByVal Width As Long = 500, ByVal Height As Long = 20, ByVal RotationX As Long = 0, ByVal RotationY As Long = 0, ByVal RotationZ As Long = 0) As TextBoxInfo
    With New TextBoxInfo
        .Text = Text
        .Top = Top
        .Left = Left
        .Width = Width
        .Height = Height
        .RotationX = RotationX
        .RotationY = RotationY
        .RotationZ = RotationZ
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

I'd make a separate function for each individual textbox. For example:

```
Private Function ConfigureClientTextBox(ByVal source As Worksheet) As TextBoxInfo
    Set ConfigureClientTextBox = _
        TextBoxInfo.Create(source.Cells(6, 4).Value, 115, 95, RotationZ:=3)
End Function

Private Function ConfigureRequestDateTextBox(ByVal source As Worksheet) As TextBoxInfo
    Set ConfigureClientTextBox = _
        TextBoxInfo.Create(source.Cells(6, 15).Value, 127, 420, RotationZ:=2)
End Function
```

And so on. Then your "main macro" script becomes rather crystal-clear:

```
Dim textBoxInfos As VBA.Collection
Set textBoxInfos = New VBA.Collection
With textBoxInfos
    .Add ConfigureClientTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureRequestDateTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureClientLocationTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureContactPersonTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigurePhoneNumberTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureWorkDescriptionTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureInspectedByTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureDateStartedTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureDateFinishedTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureInspectedDateTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureConfirmedByTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureConfirmDateTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureMaterialsATextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureMaterialsBTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureTotalMaterialsTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureLaborTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureLaborTotalTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureTotalCostTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigurePreparedByTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureCheckedByTextBox(xlSheet)
    .Add ConfigureApprovedByTextBox(xlSheet)
End With

Dim info As TextBoxInfo
For Each info In textBoxInfos
    CreateTextBox ActiveDocument.Shapes, info
Next
```

And now if you need to add, remove, or change a textbox, you know exactly where to look... as opposed to scrolling through dozens of lines of code.

Not sure it will be faster though. But if you're doing all that with `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to `True`, consider setting it to `False` *before* the loop, and back to `True` once you're done - even in case of error:

```
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    '...
    '
    Dim textBoxInfos As VBA.Collection
    Set textBoxInfos = New VBA.Collection
    With textBoxInfos
        .Add ConfigureClientTextBox(xlSheet)
        '...
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim info As TextBoxInfo
    For Each info In textBoxInfos
        CreateTextBox ActiveDocument.Shapes, info
    Next

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xlBook.Close
    xlApp.Close
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    'todo: handle any runtime error that might happen
    Resume CleanExit
```

Comment: Wow, this will take me time to digest but thank you for answering and having patience. I will get my feedback once I have implemented your suggestion. Have a nice day! :)